# different ways to initialize array of strings in c

Tags: c, arrays, initialization, c-strings, string-literals

i am trying to initialize an array of strings in c in different ways and i'm having trouble to understand how it behaves.

i'm trying to initialize the array and print it 
,i have tried three ways to initialize the array

```
char **argv = {"foo","boo"};
char *argv[] = {"foo","boo"};
char ****argv[] = {"foo","boo"};
```

and then print them using

```
    printf("%s",argv[1]);
```

i expected the first and second one to run and the third to fail but the first one is giving me run time error and the other run without any problem
why? and how does c compile them

Comment: For your purposes, way #2 should be the best.  Please tell us more abut the "run time error" you got when you tried that.

Comment: That third one is utterly bizarre. Are you sure that's what you mean?

Comment: Note that if you plan on passing `argv` to a function like `execv()`, it needs a null pointer at the end, so it should be `{"foo", "boo", NULL}`

Comment: Try compiling with `-Wall` because these examples make `clang` refuse to compile due to wildly mismatched types.

Comment: `char **argv = {"foo","boo"};` initializes from incompatible pointer types. `char ****argv[] = {"foo","boo"};` has 3-Levels of indirection too many. `char *argv[] = {"foo","boo"};` is the only correct guess...  Always compile with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` as part of your compile string.

Comment: those are the two warning that i'm getting 

main.c:6:19: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     char **argv= {"ahmed","mohamed"};
===================================
main.c:6:27: warning: excess elements in scalar initializer
     char **argv= {"ahmed","mohamed"};

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Among these declarations

```
char **argv = {"foo","boo"};
char *argv[] = {"foo","boo"};
char ****argv[] = {"foo","boo"};
```

only the second declaration is valid.

The first declaration is not valid because you may not use a list in braces with more than one expression to initialize a scalar object. And even if you will use only one string literal in braces in the first declaration nevertheless the type of the declared variable ( `char **` ) and the type of the initializer ( `char *` ) are different and there is no implicit conversion between the types.

The third declaration is invalid because there is no implicit conversion between the type `char *` (the type of the string literals used as initializers) and the type `char ****`.

Valid declarations in C of character arrays using the presented list of initializers can be

```
char *argv1[] = {"foo","boo"};  
char argv2[][3] = {"foo","boo"};    
char argv3[][4] = {"foo","boo"};
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char *argv1[] = {"foo","boo"};  
    char argv2[][3] = {"foo","boo"};    
    char argv3[][4] = {"foo","boo"};    


    printf( "%s, %s\n", argv1[0], argv1[1] );
    printf( "%3.3s, %3.3s\n", argv2[0], argv1[1] );
    printf( "%s, %s\n", argv3[0], argv3[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
foo, boo
foo, boo
foo, boo
```

To make the first initialization correct you can write

```
char * p[] = {"foo","boo"}
char **argv = p;
```

Another way is to use the compound literal like

```
char **argv= ( char *[] ){"foo","boo"};
```

Here is one more demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    char **argv= ( char *[] ){"foo","boo"}; 


    printf( "%s, %s\n", argv[0], argv[1] );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
foo, boo
```

Comment: so how to initialize the first one properly?

Comment: @MahmoudAbdelbary I do not understand why you need such an initialization but you can write char *p = "foo"; char **argv = &p;